# Произвести преобразования в коде, чтобы он работал с русскими символами

Tags: c#

Есть программа, шифрование и дешифрование шифром плэйфера, но он работает только с латиницей. Мне же необходимо с только с русскими символами. Прошу помощи: что и где поправить, чтобы это работало с русскими символами?

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string originalText = "Defend the east wall of the castle.";
        Console.WriteLine(originalText);         
        string plainText = Playfair.Prepare(originalText);
        Console.WriteLine(plainText);
        string key = "cdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyzab";
        string cipherText = Playfair.Encipher(key, plainText);
        Console.WriteLine(cipherText);
        plainText = Playfair.Decipher(key, cipherText);
        Console.WriteLine(plainText);

        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}

public class Playfair
{

    public static string Prepare(string originalText)
    {
        int length = originalText.Length;
        originalText = originalText.ToLower();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
           char c = originalText[i];
           if (c >= 97 && c <= 122)
           {
              // If the second letter of a pair is the same as the first, insert an 'x' 
              if (sb.Length % 2 == 1 && sb[sb.Length - 1] == c)
              {                                 
                 sb.Append('x');
              }
              sb.Append(c);
           }
        }

        // If the string is an odd length, append an 'x'
        if (sb.Length % 2 == 1)
        {
           sb.Append('x');
        }

        return sb.ToString();     
    }

    public static string Encipher(string key, string plainText)
    {
        int length = plainText.Length; 
        char a,b;   
        int a_ind, b_ind, a_row, b_row, a_col, b_col;   
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i+=2)
        {
           a = plainText[i];
           b = plainText[i+1];

           a_ind = key.IndexOf(a);
           b_ind = key.IndexOf(b);
           a_row = a_ind / 5;
           b_row = b_ind / 5;
           a_col = a_ind % 5;
           b_col = b_ind % 5;

           if(a_row == b_row)
           {
              if(a_col == 4)
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind - 4]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind + 1]);
              }
              else if(b_col == 4)
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind + 1]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind - 4]);
              } 
              else
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind + 1]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind + 1]);
              }
            }
            else if(a_col == b_col)
            {
              if(a_row == 4)
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind - 20]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind + 5]);
              }
              else if(b_row == 4)
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind + 5]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind - 20]);
              }
              else
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind + 5]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind + 5]);
              }
           }
           else
           {
               sb.Append(key[5*a_row + b_col]);
               sb.Append(key[5*b_row + a_col]);
           }       
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static string Decipher(string key, string cipherText)
    {
        int length = cipherText.Length; 
        char a,b;   
        int a_ind, b_ind, a_row, b_row, a_col, b_col;   
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i+=2)
        {
           a = cipherText[i];
           b = cipherText[i+1];

           a_ind = key.IndexOf(a);
           b_ind = key.IndexOf(b);
           a_row = a_ind / 5;
           b_row = b_ind / 5;
           a_col = a_ind % 5;
           b_col = b_ind % 5;

           if(a_row == b_row)
           {
              if(a_col == 0)
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind + 4]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind - 1]);
              }
              else if(b_col == 0)
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind - 1]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind + 4]);
              } 
              else
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind - 1]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind - 1]);
              }
            }
            else if(a_col == b_col)
            {
              if(a_row == 0)
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind + 20]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind - 5]);
              }
              else if(b_row == 0)
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind - 5]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind + 20]);
              }
              else
              {
                  sb.Append(key[a_ind - 5]);
                  sb.Append(key[b_ind - 5]);
              }
           }
           else
           {
               sb.Append(key[5*a_row + b_col]);
               sb.Append(key[5*b_row + a_col]);
           }       
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ispirato, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Тут

> string key =
> "cdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyzab";

Заменить на буквы кириллицы (полный алфавит)

В

> public static string Prepare(string
> originalText)

Во всех вхождениях строчки

> sb.Append('x');
> Заменить 'x' на букву кирилического алфавита. Полагаю что подойдёт любая, но не уверен (т.к. в сам алгоритм шифрования особо не вникал)

В остальном коде вроде как привязки к конкретному алфавиту нет...